# Woocommerce exclude products by different users

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have differents shopmanager in my wocommerce, but for now i want that 1 shopmanager can see only all products created from him/her not all. For now they can only modify these products but i want hide different products from different shopmanager..

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_pre_get_posts' );

function custom_pre_get_posts( $q ) {

        if ( ! $q->is_main_query() ) return;

        if ( ! $q->is_post_type_archive() ) return;

        if ( ! ( current_user_can( 'edit_product' ) ) && is_shop() ) {
                    $q->query_vars['author'] = get_current_user_id();

        }

remove_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_pre_get_posts_query' ); 

}
```

Try this snippet

Comment: u can apply 'post_type' in query_vars  , will  update my answer